# Re-installing newer Ubuntu- does "Erase Ubuntu....... and reinstall" delete grub?

Tags: grub2, upgrade, system-installation

I have Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 with grub providing dual boot. I would like to upgrade the Ubuntu via a re-installation and keep my grub so I can dual boot.

I am at the point in the installation process where I am presented with the screen:

"This computer currently has Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS".....

Am I ok selecting "Erase Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS and reinstall"? My grub will not get deleted?

Comment: Grub won't be messed with until the end, when the installer will overwrite grub. The installer will then run the command, `update-grub`, at which point it will see that you have windows installed, and create a new menu. You should be safe.

Comment: If you install ubuntu again it's won't mess up your grub. But problem will happen if you want to reinstall windows :) as because windows don't like other OS :P

Answer (score 1):

Since the grub config file is stored on the partitions that you're going to be formatting, yes, your previous GRUB installation will disappear - but as Max said above in comments, it will run update-grub to generate a new menu. It should pick up Windows and any other GRUB entries that the previous Ubuntu installation would have added to the menu.